# Etiquette: Should I edit questions with "Thanks" or wait for Moderator?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, editing

I have a question, which to some might be a bit close to splitting hairs: Should I edit a question if there are things like:

> Thanks in advance
>
> UserNoName

or the code is not properly highlighted or there is some other slight deviation from the usual question format?

Or should I just wait until a moderator cleans it up? (I must confess I got the editing privilege recently and am a bit anxious to try it out...  :) )

Comment: A related question, possibly also helpful: [When is it (and isn't) acceptable to edit?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340/when-is-it-and-isnt-acceptable-to-edit)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you see a question which can be improved, go ahead and edit it. Community editing makes our site outstanding and is a reason for its quality.

Of course we all should edit sensibly. And we should not edit too much in a row to not flood the front page.

Btw. I don't see that it's urgent to remove a friendly "Thanks" in a new question of a new user to avoid unsettling him. However older questions can be cleaned up without hesitating. It would just be good to improve it a bit further besides a small edit removing "Thanks" and alike.

See also: [In Defense of Editing](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/).

Comment: +1. Just want to add that it is possible to edit without edit privilege, the edit only must be review later. (And probably reviewing is faster then editing, thus you can help by this.)

Comment: Why is desirable to remove the "Thanks" at all? I.e. why are thanks inappropriate?

Comment: @QuinnCulver Looking on only one question maybe. But it is not useful to have to read the same with every question. People answering here are willing to help you and need no "Please help" and "Thank you" in the question (I see that is data garbage, the same why I do not like emails written in  html garbage).  Perhaps that is old fashioned ...