# Why we should not use "Thanks" and why should we use it?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, etiquette, up-votes

I am a new user and find hard when I get the answer to my question and I have this restriction "do not say "Thanks"". I want to say, but I shouldn't, so I give an upvote (now I can). I want to know what are the short lists of pro and cons against the use of "Thanks", this nice word, in Tex-sx.

I see that there are already some nice posts about the cons, such as [Why is “thanks” inappropriate](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/why-is-thanks-inappropriate-at-the-end-of-a-question). What are the pros of using it?

I'm also interesting in hear about if we should think about having a code symbol in LaTeX to "Thanks" and how more expert users are used to say (secretely) "Thanks" in Tex.sx.

Comment: I think the Linked Q talks about "Thank you in Questions by OP" it may be to make `Q` content stay focussed. For Answers: If you want answerers to know that you upvoted and display your gratitude towards their answers. Comment as "+1 Thank you so much" below their answer. In this way you do both the Official `upvote` and unofficial/emotional `thanks`.

Comment: Also if you are like [this user](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19356), you can offer Bounty to say BIG costly thank you :)

Comment: It's not really uncommon that users add a »Thank You« comment to a helpful answer although comments are supposed to clarify questions/answers. I actually do like those comments :)

Comment: There is no such rule, nevermind that. here are more http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3802/previous-editing-and-etiquette-discussions

Comment: The "best" way to say thanks IMO is to upvote (and accept) the answer. That's how the rep system works.

Comment: Related: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/168244)

Comment: Instead of a "Thank you" comment, consider writing some (positive) feedback on the answer, saying why it was helpful to you. That also makes the answerer feel appreciated and can add some real value.

Comment: @Caramdir I tend to agree with you, although give to much (positive) feedback could lead to missing the idea of being parsimonious and get right to the point. I see there is a lot of different opinions. Can some one bring up one general answer? Or a pool of answers stating the different views if relevant?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We don't follow the *Thanks* removal rule. It is a SO thing.

Some of us approve Thanks removing edits. Some don't.

I don't.

---

Some notes for future reference and responding to a hypothetical SO user arriving here.

- I'm not bothered with Thanks word. It's a word. Why don't we get equally bothered by those voting arrows next to the question or those colorful badge numbers? Yes, I know the answer.
- I can't believe that one word disrupts the preceeding question text. If you are bothered one word probably your RAM memory is the culprit not the question.
- I don't understand why this is still an issue. I'm amazed by the fact that asking for MWE is still not respected but any new user starts removing thanks. If you care start from MWEs not from the weirdest SO rule.
- I've read the SO thread. None of them makes sense to me. We are not preparing documentation for TeX/Python/C/etc. But *A question is a knowledge source, must be as minimal as possible, free from ....* no it very isn't
- We care about new users and our new users are not necessarily hardcore coders. They might not be even aware of SO. They come here and casually post a question about (La)TeX and somebody removes *Thanks* from the question. There you go; You explain to any sensible person why this is happening without annoying them.

Comment: You sir are epic! `❤`