# Previous editing and etiquette discussions

Tags: discussion, editing, etiquette, big-list

We have a recurring theme of Official capitalization of (La)TeX and friends, removing *Thanks*, code blocking code snippets, retagging, grammar fixing etc. discussion here on Meta-TeX-SX.

The reason for this question is to compile yet another big list for a little bit of coherence on the individual policies which might contradict with another when combined. So I thought it might be helpful if we had a big list that we can refer to.

For that reason I can think of two families of editing reasons that are completely grouped according to my personal opinion;

1. **Content and convenience**: Fixing simple MWE mistakes, completion of MWEs, code block formatting (both inline and as a standalone block), tagging, retagging, link prettifying (SX engine modifies the link if a TeX-SX link is pasted directly), picture inclusion, picture renewal if expired and others
2. **Structure and Appearance**: Capitalization of TeX, LaTeX etc., grammar fixes, removing greetings and thanks, removing signatures, and others that can be regarded as *"while you are at it..."* reasons.

Can we make a question list for each of these items which had discussed the etiquette one way or the other for convenience?

If you don't agree with this please downvote (I mean it) so we can close/remove this.

Finally, this is somewhat different than [When is (and isn't) it acceptable to edit?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340/when-is-and-isnt-it-acceptable-to-edit) because that question discusses whether we should edit or not, here I want to compile the previous discussions in case of a referral need.

I'll give two examples below for clarifying this proposal.

Answer (score 10):

### Capitalization (of TeX, LaTeX and Friends) and Markup

- [Prompting the user to change "latex" to LaTeX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3799/prompting-the-user-to-change-latex-to-latex)
- ["Official" capitalizations of words from the TeX world](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2407/official-capitalizations-of-words-from-the-tex-world)
- [What is the policy on adding keyboard markup?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4511/what-is-the-policy-on-adding-keyboard-markup)

Comment: It also needs a separate *capitalization of barbara beeton's answers* :P

Comment: I've taken the liberty of organizing things a bit differently, adding another answer for some of the questions prompted by barbara's style, which I think fit more nicely with [Sean's recent question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4509/should-we-edit-popular-questions-to-be-model-questions-new-users-can-pattern-a). Moreover, I've added [cfr's recent question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4511/what-is-the-policy-on-adding-keyboard-markup) to this answer. Please feel free to undo this if you prefer something different, percusse.

Comment: @AdamLiter Liberty access granted indefinitely. :P It's better indeed. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

### Removing greetings, "Thanks" and signature

- [Removing "thanks" from questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3602/removing-thanks-from-questions)
- [Why is "thanks" inappropriate at the end of a question?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/why-is-thanks-inappropriate-at-the-end-of-a-question)
- [Etiquette: Should I edit questions with "Thanks" or wait for Moderator?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1961/etiquette-should-i-edit-questions-with-thanks-or-wait-for-moderator)
- [What to do about a post when the OP insists on putting a thanks at the end?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4478/what-to-do-about-a-post-when-the-op-insists-on-putting-a-thanks-at-the-end)

Answer (score 9):

### Answers in the comments

- [Adding the "accepted" mark to a question or to a comment](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/adding-the-accepted-mark-to-a-question-or-to-a-comment)
- [What if a comment answers a question?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/what-if-a-comment-answers-a-question)
- [Why do people answer in comments?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/why-do-people-answer-in-comments)

Answer (score 1):

### Etiquette: respecting OP's style, intent, and contribution

- [Respecting poster's style](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2097/respecting-posters-style)
- [Why were my edits rejected?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2599/why-were-my-edits-rejected)
- [Consensus vs accepted answers on meta](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4514/consensus-vs-accepted-answers-on-meta)
- [Should we edit popular questions to be 'model' questions new users can pattern after?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4509/should-we-edit-popular-questions-to-be-model-questions-new-users-can-pattern-a)